# How to clear a table cell value if it is zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `JSP` with the following table.

```
<table id="grid">
<tr class="row">
                <td class="cell"><input type="number" maxlength="1" id="00" value="${array[0][0]}"></td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="number" maxlength="1" id="01" value="${array[0][1]}"></td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="number" maxlength="1" id="02" value="${array[0][2]}"></td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="number" maxlength="1" id="03" value="${array[0][3]}"></td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="number" maxlength="1" id="04" value="${array[0][4]}"></td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="number" maxlength="1" id="05" value="${array[0][5]}"></td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="number" maxlength="1" id="06" value="${array[0][6]}"></td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="number" maxlength="1" id="07" value="${array[0][7]}"></td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="number" maxlength="1" id="08" value="${array[0][8]}"></td>

            </tr>
........................9 rows like the above.................
</table>
```

I have tried the following `jQuery` code to clear the contents of the table cell's input value if it zero. But it is not working. Can anyone guide?

```
$("#grid td input").each(function(){
  $(this).each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 0) {
            $(this).empty();
        }
     })
});
```

Comment: You want to remove input or remove value?

Comment: @dfsq just clear it so that the user can fill a valid digit

Comment: But all have a value of ${array[0]...} so nothing will be cleared.

Comment: @JamesKyburz That is the problem I am facing. The page when loaded comes with a grid with some zeros and non zeroes. Only zeros are to be cleared. array is an attribute in the servlet context.

Comment: I posted answer based on your original question which does not mentioned that input inside cell. However, you can easily extend it to make it work.

Comment: Well as many have answered using val instead of empty which just clears the innerHTML which for an input won't clear the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the value you have to use `$(this).val('');`

```
$("#grid td input").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 0) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
});
```

`empty` remove all child nodes of the set of element and does not clear the input. jQuery.empty docs: http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score 1):

dont use each inside each , each already refers to your input , so just use :

```
$("#grid td input").each(function(){


        if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            $(this).val("")
        }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you use $("#grid td input").each, so you won't need to use $(this).each, just use $(this).val("")

```
$("#grid td input").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 0) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For example like this:

```
$("#grid td input").val(function() {
    return this.value == 0 ? '' : this.value;
});
```

[$.fn.empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) is used to clear HTML nodes. To set an input element value you use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method. You can simply use native HTMLInputElement value property.

Also you can use val directly without `each`, jQuery will iterate over the collection internally for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `this` inside your `each`, it is referring to the input element, and not the `td` element. Since input elements don't have any child nodes, and `$().empty()` is used to remove child nodes from an element, nothing will happen.

If you want to completely remove the input, you should use `$(this).parent().empty()`, which will empty the parent of the input, ie the `td` element. I assume though that you want to keep the input element there, but just remove it's value, in which case you should simply do `$(this).val("")`, which will set the value of the input to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working demo :](http://jsbin.com/qoton/1/edit)**

```
$("#grid td input").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val()== 0) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
});
```

Comment: no '0' == 0 //true
the correct comparison operator without type conversion is ===

Comment: Although == will work, it is better to check the '0' value with ===, in this case this value is always a string... removed the downvote anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

code will not work properly because
 input type is number (type="number") so it will not give proper value, and you have given non Numeric value to inputbox

in short  value="${array[0][0]}" is worng for input box with type="number"
and use $(this).val(''); to clear value in inputbox

Answer (score 0):

Please find solution in following plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/lmuHfLWMYvgv2rjM1oGc?p=info